# not closing socket connections, want to use bind()

Tags: python, sockets, bind

I am using websocket-client in python2.7 and am opening many connections for a websocket interaction.

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json

def openTick():
    signal = 0
    bfnxWS = "wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws"
    ws = create_connection(bfnxWS)

    ws.send(json.dumps({
        "event": "subscribe",
        "channel": "ticker",
        "pair": "BTCUSD",
    }))

    while True:
        result = ws.recv()
        result = json.loads(result)
        #print result
        for index, i in enumerate(result):
            if index == 1:
                if type(i) != unicode:
                    return i

    ws.close()
```

This interaction is being called multiple times in my main function and each time it opens a new connection.

I had read about bind() in tutorials on youtube and in other modules. But can not find a way to implement it in this module.

It seems like such an easy fix that I don't want to switch to autobahn or something else.

The goal is to use the same connection. Can anyone give me some tips on using the same connection once I create it. Right now open connections are accumulating on my machine and causing errors to get thrown.

Here is the netstat output showing the accumulating connections...

```
tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    ESTABLISHED


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    ESTABLISHED


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47120              104.16.173.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:55812              104.16.172.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:59666              104.16.171.181:https    ESTABLISHED


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47120              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55812              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:59666              104.16.171.181:https    ESTABLISHED


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47120              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47998              104.16.175.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:55812              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:59666              104.16.171.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     96 neo:47130              104.16.173.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:48480              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47120              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47998              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55812              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp       49      0 neo:59666              104.16.171.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:47130              104.16.173.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:55822              104.16.172.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:48480              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:59676              104.16.171.181:https    TIME_WAIT  


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47120              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47998              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55812              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48008              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55822              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48480              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:59676              104.16.171.181:https    TIME_WAIT  


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0    126 neo:48490              104.16.174.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:47120              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47998              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55812              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47140              104.16.173.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:48008              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55822              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48480              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:59676              104.16.171.181:https    TIME_WAIT  


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48490              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47120              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47998              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55812              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47140              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48008              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55822              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55832              104.16.172.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:59686              104.16.171.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48480              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:59676              104.16.171.181:https    TIME_WAIT  


tcp        0      0 neo:47116              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48470              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48490              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47120              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47998              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55812              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:47140              104.16.173.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48008              104.16.175.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:55822              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48500              104.16.174.181:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 neo:55832              104.16.172.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:59686              104.16.171.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:48480              104.16.174.181:https    TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 neo:59676              104.16.171.181:https    TIME_WAIT
```

how do I bind the receiving port so I don't accumulate connection or how do I efficiently close() the connections?

Comment: Perhaps if you moved the ``ws.close()`` to some place where it could actually be called, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: hey i tried moving it after the return and then a single indent from its current position and the interaction starts getting closed after the first line displaying the headers of the channel it is subscribing too. I am going to try a count method to keep it alive , but I know there are built in methods I am missing, in either the type of connection I am creating or binding a long lived connection to a single port

Comment: or instead of closing the connection is there a way to reference the same connection that is long lived